# Vivado: Mismatch between behavioral simulation and post-synthesis functional simulation

Tags: vhdl, synthesis

I have a strange problem in Vivado. The goal is to initialize spi for an adc with the Xilinx Artix-100T FPGA in VHDL. But, there is a mismatch between the behavioral simulation and post-synthesis functional simulation in Vivado 2021.1.

In the behavioral simulation, the signal *reset_n* is 0 for one clock cycle and then rises to 1 (as it should). But, in the post-synthesis functional simulation, it is always 0. Is there any explanation for this? I also tried synthesis attributes like KEEP, DONT_TOUCH, but with no luck.

I reduced the whole logic to a few lines of code to show the part where this happens.

The Main file:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity Main is

    port(
        clock   : IN     STD_LOGIC;                      --system clock;
        res : out std_logic := '0';
        reset_done : out std_logic := '0');

    signal init_done :boolean := false;
    --    signal res : std_logic := '0';

end Main;

architecture Behavioral of Main is

begin

    test: process is
    begin
        if (reset_done = '0') then
            res <= '0';
            wait until rising_edge(clock);
            res <= '1';
            reset_done <= '1';
        else
            wait until rising_edge(clock);
        end if;
    end process test;

end Behavioral;
```

The test bench file:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;


entity Main_tb is
end Main_tb;

architecture Behavioral of Main_tb is

component Main is

port(
    clock   : IN     STD_LOGIC;                             
    res : out std_logic := '0';
    reset_done : out std_logic := '0');                            
end component;

--signals
signal clock : std_logic := '1';
signal res :std_logic := '0';
signal reset_done : std_logic := '0';

begin

    simulation: Main
        port map (clock, res, reset_done);
        
    --100 MHz clock
    clk_stimulus: process
    begin
        wait for 5 ns;
        clock <= not clock;
    end process clk_stimulus;

end Behavioral;
```

Behavioral simulation:
[image: sim]

Post-synthesis functional simulation:
[image: post-sim]

New working code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity Main is

    port(
        clock   : IN     STD_LOGIC;     --system clock;
        res : out std_logic := '0';     --init signal
        reset_done : out std_logic := '0');     --init signal
end Main;

architecture Behavioral of Main is

begin

    test: process(clock) is 
    begin
        if (rising_edge(clock)) then -- preferred syntax
            res <= '1';
            reset_done <= '1';
        end if;
    end process test;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: You are using a very odd template for a synthesisable clocked process; have you tried using one of the recommended ones in the synthesis style guide?

Comment: What would you change in this process?

Comment: _"there is a mismatch between the behavioral simulation and post-synthesis functional simulation"_ that's not strange at all. That's quite normal actually.

Comment: But, how can I debug this when there is a mismatch?

Comment: First, looking at reset_done in both simulations will probably reveal the problem. Then, do some study of what happens to initialisation clauses on signal declarations during synthesis.

Comment: I looked into the "Vivado Design Suite User Guide Synthesis". Now, the signals are initialized with a default value. But, the same issue. What's interesting, in the behavioral simulation, "reset_done" goes high one clock cycle before "res" does it (see new figures)! Furthermore, when I change the transition of the signal "res" from 1 to 0, it does the opposite thing but in parallel with the "reset_done" !?

Comment: It has something to do with the signal assignment before the "wait until rising_edge(clock)". When I also add the command "reset_done <= '0'" after "res <= '0'", the signal "reset_done" stays also 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mismatch means that the synthesizer could not infer the correct logic form your VHDL description: the synthesis doesn't understand the entirety of VHDL. You have to program it in a specific way, as described in the HDL coding guidelines.

That's the whole reason we do post-synthesis simulation: to verify that the synthesizer understood our code.

Due to signal initialization, power-on-reset is rarely needed in good designs.

Anyhow, if you strip your code down to the core, it says:

```vhdl
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity Main is
    port(
        clock : in std_logic;
        res : out std_logic;
        reset_done : out std_logic);
end Main;

architecture Behavioral of Main is
    signal i_res : std_logic := '0'; -- initialize
    signal i_reset_done : std_logic := '0';
begin
    test: process(clk) is 
    begin
        if (rising_edge(clk)) then -- preferred syntax
            i_res <= i_reset_done;
            i_reset_done <= '1'; -- set once.
        end if;
    end process test;
    res <= i_res;
    reset_done <= i_reset_done;
end Behavioral;
```

I don't get why `reset_done` has to be asserted one clock before `res`, but anyhow.

You could also infer a shift-register to realize a multi-clock cycle reset.

Comment: First, thanks for this detailed answer. But, I have some questions about it: 1. How often are the commands "res <= i_res; and reset_done <= i_reset_done;" executed? 2. Should I avoid the command "wait until rising_edge(clock)" in all designs? 3. I edited the original code to avoid additional signals. It is working now as intended. What do you think of it?

Comment: @Sebastian90 commands?? executed?? What do you know about VHDL? And FPGA's in general? There are no "commands" here. Nothing is "executed". You're not programing instructions for a CPU. You're telling the synthesizer that the internal signals (e.g. `i_res`) should be connected to the external signal (`res`)

Comment: @Sebastian90 2) yes, for now avoid `wait for ...`. It _is_ allowed, but as you can see easy to have errors. 3) internal signals are often preferred, as initialization of output signals can have issues. But if this works and keeps working. Leave it like you want. **NOTE** the code you show has different behavior from the first code you give and the simulation you show. `reset_done` was asserted one clock cycle before `rst` in your fist code.

Comment: I am working since 3 months with VHDL and FGPA's. Before that, I worked with C++ and Matlab. So, I am used to the words "commands" and "executed". The intention was that both signals go to 1 at the same time. One final question: Could you state what was wrong with my first version of the code, because I want to avoid these pitfalls in the future?